# multicore and coprocessor means same?

Tags: arm, multicore

I have doubht while understanding the meaning of ARM CortexA15.

my understanding is, it will have one processor(CPU) with 15 cores which uses ARMv7 architecture. Please correct me if this understanding is not correct.

multicore and coprocessor means the same or different. Can you help to understand if they are different.

Comment: historically, multicore = more than one of the same execution core in a single chip die, e.g. intel i5 = 4 cores. coprocessor = related-but-different core, not necessarily on the same die, e.g. intel 387 math coprocessor hooked up with a 386 cpu.

Comment: Coprocessor seems to be an obsolete hardware chip, however you can see more about on wikipedia.

Comment: **multicore** means multiples of the same CPU (symmetric multiprocessor or SMP).  A co-process can be looked at as asymmetric (AMP),  or just an assistive device like a math co-processor.  For the ARM, a coprocessor usually refers to MMU and system configuration registers as well as NEON/VFP.  It is not usually another CPU as most people understand.  There are some 'AMP' ARM systems with an Cortex-M and Cortex-A CPU.  ARM intended the Cortex-R for such applications.

Comment: I can understood as 
[multi-core: duplication of same execution unit(say 2 execution units for dual core) in a single chip and any instruction/task can execute on any core(depends on scheduler and pipeline).]
[coprocessor: different execution unit which can execute specific instructions/tasks(say floating point caliculation).]

Answer (score 1):

A15 is just an ARM processor(CPU) model number. It comes with 1 - 4 cores and is based on ARM v7a.

Co-processors are compute units that help ARM (or any other processor for that matter) to do its operations more efficiently.

Multi-core means there is more than one CORE in the CPU.

Eg. Verstaile Express is a two CPU cluster based on a multicore 2x A15 and 3x A7 processors.

Comment: While checking assembly file in U-boot source for Cortex-A15 based board, I come across instructions which updates coprocessor 15 registers to disable cache, MMU etc.
Does Cortex A15 will have 15 coprocessors?

Comment: @user3693586 The architecture allows for 16 coprocessors to be _addressed_ - in the old days when there was an actual external coprocessor interface, cp0-cp7 were available for implementers to wire up their own external stuff, while cp8-cp15 are reserved for ARM's own add-ons. On modern designs, the "coprocessor" ISA is really just a historical hangover for things which are now tightly integrated into the CPU (cp10 and cp11 for VFP/NEON, cp14 for debug and cp15 for system control).

Comment: Each core will have its own cp15 for system control? so that we can disable or enable the cache of specific core.
For Jacinto6 SoC the MPU is meantioned as "2 x ARM Cortex-A15", can you please tell me what exactly it means?
Does it mean the SoC will have two Cortex-A15 MPUs and each Cortex-A15 will have 4 cores(as update bu Arun above).